# Obfuscation alternatives

Tags: php, obfuscation

So I've made a tool for web developers and now I want to sell it, but I don't want all web developers to see my code (PHP).

I do know there are PHP Obfuscators, but I don't want to use them, as they are not **COMPLETELY** 100% secure. I tried looking for a compiler for PHP (I know they aren't 100% secure as well, but they are more secure than an obfuscator,) but with no luck.

Can someone offer alternatives other than using an obfuscator?

Comment: Related answer here: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/40079/12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't want the user to have access to your code, you must not let them run it on their machine. It's that simple. As you already found out yourself, obfuscation doesn't work.

So what option do you have?

Run it on your own servers and offer it to the customer as a service, for example via SOAP. The drawbacks are that you need to administrate servers now, and that there is a latency when your service is used. But on the upside, you can write Cloud(tm) all over your marketing material.

Comment: This isn't really what i was looking for. I know i could put it on my server, but the problem is, i don't want all the traffic to be on my server, and if my host goes down, it will affect every single customer i have. But i guess there is no other choice.... Thanks for Info.

Comment: +1 for "Cloud(tm)" haw haw. Well, perhaps you could distribute your server program to *many* servers, then it would not go down? An alternative is to avoid the hassle of monetization and just give it away for free. If everyone did that, no one would have to work! (Monet might not agree)